# MediaControllerCompat - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad direction 3

Tags: android, audio

I'm issuing a simple command to my mediaControllerCompat:

controller.adjustVolume(-1, 0);

Yet my app FCs with...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad direction 3
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1469)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
       at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.adjustStreamVolume(IAudioService.java:1097)
       at android.media.AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:952)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.adjustVolume(MediaSessionCompat.java:1376)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.access$1700(MediaSessionCompat.java:963)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase$MediaSessionStub.adjustVolume(MediaSessionCompat.java:1602)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplBase.adjustVolume(MediaControllerCompat.java:969)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat.adjustVolume(MediaControllerCompat.java:252)
       at pl.qus.xenoamp.NewMainActivity.onKeyDown(NewMainActivity.java:1149)
```

MainActivity being the caller of mentioned line... What is WRONG?!

Comment: So what is line 1149 in `NewMainActivity.java`?

Comment: exactly as shown above the trace: controller.adjustVolume(-1,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an internal bug in the Android Support Library has been fixed as of version 23.1.0.

*Previous Answer*

This is a bug in the support library that affects pre-API 21 devices that use local playback (i.e., have not called [setPlaybackToRemote()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackToRemote(android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat))) - the order of parameters sent to [AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)) as per the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.java#1370) is incorrect - hence why the direction appearing as 3 - the value for [STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC).

You may be able to temporarily work around it by always calling [setPlaybackToRemote()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackToRemote(android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat)) on pre-API 21 devices, passing in a [VolumeProviderCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat.html) that *does* correctly call [AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)), but you must also handle the other methods of `VolumeProviderCompat` such as retrieving the max volume (via [getStreamMaxVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume(int))) and current volume (via [getStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume(int))) as well as setting the volume (via [setStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))).

Comment: I've also put in a fix to the Support Library which will hopefully mean some future version will not have this bug.

Comment: I see. Well, good to know you're aware of the bug! (I left a note in my source code so my grandchildren can remove the workaround as soon as the bug is fixed).

Comment: The fix is now live - update your dependency to 23.1.0!

Comment: Now you've made me feel really sorry for my sarcasm!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error using API 23 (not the Support Library) and running on an M device. I solved it by listening for the error and calling an API 1 method in its place, when necessary.

```
try { 
    ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { 
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(STREAM, VOLUME, FLAGS);
}
```

Since the Compat interface calls the internal methods for system volume control, you could also instantiate an instance AudioManager if you are not directly declaring one already.