# MediaSessionService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad direction 5

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I am getting the below error when i am adjusting the volume.

```
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad direction 5
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.ensureValidDirection(AudioService.java:3917)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.adjustStreamVolume(AudioService.java:1432)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioService.java:1407)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioService.java:1356)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionService$SessionManagerImpl$5.run(MediaSessionService.java:1369)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:436)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:277)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
09-30 07:45:12.815   868   868 E MediaSessionService:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:837)
```

Comment: Try and add some code so that we can better help you out...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaControllerCompat - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad direction 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883604/mediacontrollercompat-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-direction-3)